# Chrome enterprise set custom setting for extension

Tags: group-policy, google-chrome, chrome, extension, mdm

We have developed a browser extension and wish to distribute it.

A license key is required to use our chrome extension. This value should be set by the system administrators and not by individual end users.

How can we let administrators pass the license key via group policy or other device management configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Chrome ADMX you can only push extension, you can't set user settings for them.

Please read here; [Managing Extensions in Your Enterprise](https://support.google.com/chrome/a/answer/9296680?hl=en&ref_topic=9023098)

It all depend on your extension how it save the license. If it's user-based login, then all the user can log in with their account. Some extension are open to the enterprise public IP, etc..

If it's a file that is wrote with the activation code, then an admin can push the file with GPP under that folder possibly; C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately there is no way that a Firefox extension can read the license key file. With Chrome it should be possible. Since we want to support both, I guess we'll need to implement native messaging (https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/) to get license info from a binary outside of the browser scope.